# Error in using custom vectorized function in mutate/case_when

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Below is a simple code to reproduce the error. I define a simple function, vectorize it with another function using `purrr::map`, and then try to use it in a mutate case_when where the condition should normally ensure that the arguments are valid. The error occurs in the condition `if(arg1 > 0)` when `arg1 = NA`, but I don't understand why that even happens. If I apply the filter, the error disappears. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? My feeling is that it should work.

```
require(tidyverse)

f_single <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  if (arg1 > 0) {
    return(arg1 * arg2)
  }
}

f_vector <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  result <- map2_dbl(arg1, arg2, f_single)
  return(result)
}

x <- tribble(~ arg1, ~ arg2,
             NA, 1,
             2, 3,
             4, 5,)

x %>%
  # filter(!is.na(arg1)) %>%
  mutate(y = case_when(arg1 > 0 ~ f_vector(arg1, arg2)))
```

The error is the following:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `y = case_when(arg1 > 0 ~ f_vector(arg1, arg2))`.
Caused by error in `if (arg1 > 0) ...`:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: To make the example more clear I maybe should have used `!is.na(arg1)` in the `case_when` loop as the error remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Passing `NA` to an `if` statement will throw an error. You can avoid this by wrapping the condition with `isTRUE`.
2. Your code will still throw an error, because `f_single` returns `NULL` when `arg1` is missing or <= 0, but `map_*` expects a return value for every input.

Changing `f_single` as follows will solve both problems:

```
f_single <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  if (isTRUE(arg1 > 0)) {
    arg1 * arg2
  } else {
    NA_real_
  }
}

# rest of code unchanged from original

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#    arg1  arg2     y
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    NA     1    NA
# 2     2     3     6
# 3     4     5    20
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me! I did not know neither `isTRUE` nor `NA_real_`, that is really helpful. I still don't fully understand why `NA` is even passed to the `if` clause in the function when it should be excluded in the `case_when`, but may be I'm being a bit naive there. In any case this looks much better now.

Comment: Good question -- I believe that's because behind the scenes, `case_when` (and `if_else`) actually computes the full vector for each condition, then combines the results into a single vector where each element depends on the conditions. So every element of `arg1` and `arg2` do end up getting passed to your functions.

Comment: Yes that sounds sensible. I also understand that it is probably better to avoid the `case_when` altogether if possible and design it in a way that the function treats all cases properly.